# Passing Serialized object vs JSON between fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am considering different methods of passing an object from one fragment to another. I have read that passing a serialized version of an object between fragments can be a somewhat heavy transaction.

Would an alternative such as using GSON library to convert an object to JSON, and then passing the JSON string between fragment be a less memory intensive solution?

Comment: It superficially appears to me that, "either way, it's still serialization."  Only one way to find out:  try it and time it.

Answer (score 1):

Parcelable is the best option when it comes to passing data between Fragments. Its Android way of serializing the data and passing it between Activity and Fragments efficiently.

[This answer might help you also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable)